# cannot infer type arguments for ArrayAdapter<> when retrieving data from a database

Tags: java, android, listview, android-sqlite

My code is here please tell me what is the problem.
when i want to retrieve data from SQlite database the it give me the following error.
Please someone tell me what is the problem  in my code

```
public class ViewData extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper mDb;
TextView EList;
Button mBtn;
ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_data);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonList);
    mDb=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    view1All();



}


public void view1All() {
    mBtn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    ArrayList<String> theList=new ArrayList<>();

                    Cursor res = mDb.getAllData();
                    if(res.getCount() == 0) {
                        // show message
                      //  showMessage("Error","Nothing found");
                      //  return;
                    }




                    while (res.moveToNext()) {
                        theList.add(res.getString(1));
                        ListAdapter listAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,theList);
                        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    }


                }
            }
    );
}

}
```

Comment: while (res.moveToNext()) {
                            theList.add(res.getString(1));
                            ListAdapter listAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,theList);
                            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                        }

Comment: you are doing very bad thing in your while loop. You are creating instance of adapter in every iteration